# in app purchases question

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am looking into the iPhone in app purchased models and need to implement a subscription. Ex content will be available for 24 hours. Now the most important thing is that it needs to be available on all the other devices, so bought on the iPhone, viewable on the iPad. I'm not sure how this works ? I need to store some information on the developer server but is this the transaction id and current date/time so when launching the app on the iPad, you will attempt to buy the content again. Apple will see that this user already bought that and hopefully returns the transaction ID. At that moment I can verify if the time limit it still valid or not. 
Can anyone confirm this method off working?
If this is correct is there a 'renew'?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong.

You just need to store the "receipt-data", don't need to store transaction id and current date/time. Obviously you have to create the kind of product as "subscriptions", this will ensure that the purchased product is shared on all user's devices.

[How to verify a receipt with the AppStore.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104-SW1)

Comment: It's clear I can get the dateTime from the receipt but the question is how I can get the receipt for that particular user? There is no user object defined?

Comment: I think that when user purchase again the subscription product, Apple will restore the transaction for you, you don't have to deal with that.